# ETS Confidence Intervals in R are several orders of magnitude larger than the time series itself?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, prediction-interval, exponential-smoothing

I am forecasting a time series with confidence intervals using the `ets` model in R. Here is the time series:

[image]

Running the following R code:

```
library("forecast")

x <- c(528, 903, 684,  564,  624,  426, 1722, 1185, 1761,  500, 1100,
       735, 714, 504,  180,  549,  630,  393, 1272, 1671, 7164,   36,
       21,  57, 78,  117,  216,  423,  294,  420,  672,  867,  828,
       8000, 6000, 2322)

autoets_func = function(df, h, freq){{
  model <- ets(ts(df, frequency=freq), model="ZZZ")
  fcst = forecast(model, h=h)
  return(fcst)
}}
autoets_func(x, 19, 12)
```

produces the following "Lo 95" and "Hi 95" forecast confidence intervals:

[image]

Regardless of whether ETS is an ideal model in this situation, the confidence interval is absurdly large. Since the time series dips so close to zero, on a hunch I tried first shifting the time series up by twice its mean, producing a forecast on the shifted time series, and then shifting the forecast back down. This produced the following more reasonable result:

[image]

Given how robust and popular the function is, I doubt there is an error in `ets` itself. Might this be a weird edge case with this particular time series?